# Message bundle parameter is not replaced by label

Tags: jsf

I defined my bundle in faces-config.xml:

```
<application>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>pt_BR</default-locale>
    </locale-config>
    <message-bundle>ValidationMessages</message-bundle>
</application>
```

This is the ValidationMessages.properties:

```
javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message={1} não deve ser nulo
```

And here an inputText:

```
<p:inputText id="contato" label="Contato" value="#{solicitacaoController.solicitacao.contato}" />
```

If I submit the form without filling the inputText above I get this message:

```
{1} não deve ser nulo
```

Anyone know why {1} is not replaced by the inputText label?

Comment: have you tried with `{0}`?

Comment: I just tried, but {0} also doesn't work.

Comment: if you have `javax.validation.constraints.Max.message` the validator passes a `{value}` param to the message like so - "must be less than or equal to {value}". I don't think that `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` expects any parameters.

Comment: But when I use a p:messages and it displays various error messages from many inputTexts, how will the user know which message is related to each inputText?

Comment: you need a `<p:message for="inputId" />` for each input.

Comment: [`javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tapestry/tapestry5/trunk/tapestry-beanvalidator/src/test/resources/ValidationMessages_en.properties) does not accept any message parameter(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so many months I finally found out what was needed to make the message's parameters to work.

I had to add this to my Message.properties file:

```
javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.MESSAGE={1} {0}
```